# SQL join tables and CASE with CONCAT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm a SQL newb... and I need to join two tables (see below)

```
Table A
| id | Recipe_Web_Codes   |
|----|--------------------|
|  1 | GF VGT             |
|  2 |                    |
|  3 | VGN                |
```

```
Table B
| id | Recipe_Web_Code | Webcode_Fullname       | Color   |
|----|-----------------|------------------------|---------|
|  1 | VGT             | Vegetarian             | #ff6038 |
|  2 | VGN             | Vegan Friendly         | #97002d |
|  3 | GF              | Gluten Friendly        | #6ca4b6 |
```

and produce the following table:

```
RESULT
| id | Recipe_Web_Codes | Wecode_Fullname               | Color            |
|-------------------------------------------------------|------------------|
| 1  | GF VGT           | Gluten Friendly, Vegetarian   | #6ca4b6, #ff6038 |
| 2  |                  |                               |                  |
| 3  | VGN              | Vegan Friendly                | #97002d          |
```

I honestly don't know where to begin. I tried this but got stuck on how to concatenate case results into a single field.  Am I on the right track?

```
select Recipe_Web_Codes, Webcode_Fullname =  
    case 
        when Recipe_Web_Codes like '%VGT%' then (select Webcode_Fullname FROM TABLE_B where Recipe_Web_Code = 'VGT')
        when Recipe_Web_Codes like '%VGN%' then (select Webcode_Fullname FROM TABLE_B where Recipe_Web_Code = 'VGN')
        when Recipe_Web_Codes like '%GF%' then (select Webcode_Fullname FROM TABLE_B where Recipe_Web_Code = 'GF')
    end, 
    Color = 
    case 
        when Recipe_Web_Codes like '%VGT%' then (select Color FROM TABLE_B where Recipe_Web_Code = 'VGT')
        when Recipe_Web_Codes like '%VGN%' then (select Color FROM TABLE_B where Recipe_Web_Code = 'VGN')
        when Recipe_Web_Codes like '%GF%' then (select Color FROM TABLE_B where Recipe_Web_Code = 'GF')
    end
from TABLE_A
```

EDIT: It just clicked on me that I missed a very important point as to why I need to aggregate these strings.  The resulting table is going to be exported to JSON by another separate process, so no point to mention database normalization. Also, this is SQL 2016 SP2 so I don't have the fuction for String_agg available.

Comment: This is a very badly design.  Please learn database normalization.

Comment: Your database design is really weird because of the presence of ```Recipe_Web_Codes``` in table A. Table A should reference the ```id``` of table B. Is it something that you can change before anyone answer ? (And actually with the fields you currently show, I don't understand why you have 2 tables.

Comment: agreed about table/db design is horrible, not my work, but it's what I have to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be storing multiple values in a single column, so I would advise you to fix your data model.

That said, you can do what you want by pulling apart the strings and re-aggregating:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a outer apply
     (select string_agg(b.Webcode_Fullname, ',') as Webcode_Fullname,
             string_agg(b.Webcode_Fullname, ',') as Colors
      from string_split(a.recipe_web_codes, ' ') s join
           b
           on s.value = b.Recipe_Web_Code
     ) b;
```

Very important:  `string_split()` does not guarantee the ordering of the values.  If the ordering of the resulting strings is important, you can handle this -- assuming you have no duplicates -- by using logic such as:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a outer apply
     (select string_agg(b.Webcode_Fullname, ',') within group (order by charindex(b.Recipe_Web_Codeas, a.recipe_web_codes)) as Webcode_Fullname,
             string_agg(b.Webcode_Fullname, ',') within group (order by charindex(b.Recipe_Web_Codeas, a.recipe_web_codes)) as Colors
      from string_split(a.recipe_web_codes, ' ') s join
           b
           on s.value = b.Recipe_Web_Code
     ) b;
```

Let me emphasize again that you should put your effort into fixing your data model, by having a separate table for the recipe web codes, with one row per code.

EDIT:

One solution for older versions is a recursive CTE:

```
with bs as (
      select b.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from b
     ),
     cte as (
      select a.id, convert(varchar(max), Recipe_Web_Codes) as fullnames, convert(varchar(max), Recipe_Web_Codes)  as colors, 1 as ind
      from a
      union all
      select cte.id,
             replace(cte.fullnames, bs.Recipe_Web_Code, bs.Webcode_Fullname),
             replace(cte.colors, bs.Recipe_Web_Code, bs.color),
             1 + cte.ind
      from cte join
           bs
           on cte.ind = bs.seqnum and ind < 10
     )
select cte.id, cte.fullnames, cte.colors
from (select cte.*, max(ind) over (partition by id) as max_ind
      from cte
     ) cte
where ind = max_ind ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=baa18cef7c9a6493a3834d27ab01890c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I have SQL Server 2016 SP2 so string_agg is not available to me.
Agreed on the database design... if you see the architecture of this whole application you would be shocked.

Comment: Looks promising.... I don't understand much what's going on so I'm stuck here: 
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "fullnames" of recursive query "cte".
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "colors" of recursive query "cte".

Comment: OK, fixed the types match by adding 
cast (replace(cte.fullnames, bs.Recipe_Web_Code, bs.Webcode_Fullname) as varchar(max)),
cast (replace(cte.colors, bs.Recipe_Web_Code, bs.color) as varchar(max)),
but it seems to be replacing only the last item on the list

Comment: @Geto . . . Have you seen the DB Fiddle?  All the codes are replaced.  The recursive CTE works.

Comment: I think it has to do with the types on the db, see this updated fiddle: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8f80a824a9f3dc1e33df6b94dfd3ba4d) by the way, this is all new to me, I had no idea about cte, and I'm still trying to wrap my head around recursive cte.   I still don't understand why it only replaces the last field

Comment: @Gelo . . . It works fine if you define the columns as `varchar()`/`nvarchar()`, rather than `char()` (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f29b748e66d3293af08c3f719ba3a8b3).  When you say a code `nchar(10)`, you are saying the code is really `'GF        '` -- the spaces matter.  None of these are in your "list".  You really should have a separate table, with one row per code so you don't have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a left join of the tables and the aggregate function [`string_agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (works in SQL Server 2017+):

```
select a.id, a.Recipe_Web_Codes,
  string_agg(b.Webcode_Fullname, ', ') Webcode_Fullname,
  string_agg(b.Color, ', ') Color
from Table_A a left join Table_B b
on ' ' + a.Recipe_Web_Codes + ' ' like '% ' + b.Recipe_Web_Code + ' %'
group by a.id, a.Recipe_Web_Codes
order by a.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d94bf04e44345bd5588f409b75925baf).
Results:

```
> id | Recipe_Web_Codes | Webcode_Fullname            | Color           
> -: | :--------------- | :-------------------------- | :---------------
>  1 | GF VGT           | Vegetarian, Gluten Friendly | #ff6038, #6ca4b6
>  2 | null             | null                        | null            
>  3 | VGN              | Vegan Friendly              | #97002d
```

Comment: Darn, I have SQL Server 2016 SP2